# How to get Kafka lag using Kafka 0.10?

Tags: apache-kafka

As `Kafka 0.10` isn't using Zookeeper anymore to store the lags anymore, how do I retrieve it now? Is there  way to access it from the consumers?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the latest documentation: [kafka.apache.org/documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_group) it is done the following way:

```
> bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server broker1:9092 --describe --group test-consumer-group

  TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
  test-foo                       0          1               3               2          consumer-1-a5d61779-4d04-4c50-a6d6-fb35d942642d   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Kafka 0.10.0.x:

```
 bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --new-consumer  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group your_consumer_group
```

Kafka 0.9 or earlier:

```
 bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --zookeeper  localhost:2181 --group your_consumer_group --topic your_topic
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum based on partitions you can use below command too which sums the count:

bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh — bootstrap-server kafka-server:9092 — describe -group consumer-group-name | awk ‘{sum += $5} END {print sum}’